# Set DisplayObject to pass on MouseEvents

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events

I have a Sprite I want to use as a debug layer. So I would like to overlay this layer over the normal scene and draw to it.

This is fine except for that it blocks all MouseEvents from the layers below.

Is there a way I can set an InteractiveObject to allow MouseEvent objects to "pass through" and onto the InteractiveObjects below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try sprite.mouseEnabled = false

Just incase that doesn't work try adding sprite.mouseChildren = false too

Comment: yeah the mouseChildren is only required if there are any other display objects inside the sprite.

Comment: This is correct - just make sure you use "mouseEnabled" (lowercase M), not "MouseEnabled"